# integral domains and units

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose an integral domain $D$ has a generator, i.e an element $a \in D$
>   such that  $(a) = D$ . Show that $a$ is a unit in $D$ and that every unit of
>   $D$ is a generator.

since $1 \in D$, so $1 \in (a)$ , so $ab = 1$ for some $b \in D$ therefore $a$ has inverse $b$, so is a unit in $D$.

I need help proving the second bit.

Comment: b is a 's multiplicative  inverse, thats what i showed , no?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ be a unit in $D$. You need to show $(u)=D$. But $uu^{-1}=1$, so $1\in (u)$. Thus $(1)\subset (u)$. But $(1)=D$, so $D=(u)$.